# Apache Sling index page/directory listing

Tags: aem, sling

in order to gain a basic understanding of Apache Sling I'm trying to
build a simple blogging application using it.
I defined an own node type blog:post that is used for single posts.

This is the structure of the content repository so far:

```
/
|
|-content
|   |
|   |-blog 
|       |
|       |-some-blogpost (jcr:primaryType=blog:post)
|       |-another-blogpost (jcr:primaryType=blog:post)
|-apps
    |
    |-blog (jcr:primaryType=sling:Folder)
        |
        |-post
            |
            |-html.jsp
```

I can refer to a specific blog post by opening http://example.com/blog/some-blogpost.html
Now suppose I wanted to have an overview of the most recent posts available at http://example.com/blog.

How do I have to name the necessary script and where do I have to put it?

Kind regards,

Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating separate JCR node type for each content type, I'd use `sling:resourceType` property. So you could create new blog post with `jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured` and add property `sling:resourceType=blog/post` to it.

Moving to your question: you could create new component `/apps/blog/recentPosts` (and script like `/apps/blog/recentPosts/html.jsp`) and then set `sling:resourceType=blog/recentPosts` property on the `/content/blog` node to tell Sling which script should be used to render this piece of content.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works and seems logical in hindsight. I guess it requires some time getting used to the content centric nature of Sling.